# Scan gcno for coverage to SonarQube 6.X version

Tags: sonarqube

How can I scan gcno files to SonarQube for code coverage of C files ? 
I'm using 6.3.1 version of SonarQube.
Is the best way is to convert the gcno to gcov files and then to upload ?

Thanks :)
Chen

Answer (score 0):

There is a binary called `gcov`. Check your `/usr/bin` folder if on `Linux`.

To get `gcov` files, first, move to the folder that contains your source code, then you do the following:

`gcov *.cpp -o /path/to/object/folder/\*`